# использование метода TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Есть класс представляющий данные которые будут представлены в таблице.

```
public class DataCarTable
{

    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private double price;

    public DataCarTable(String mark, String model, String color, double price)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mark
     */
    public String getMark()
    {
        return mark;
    }

    /**
     * @param mark the mark to set
     */
    public void setMark(String mark)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    /**
     * @return the model
     */
    public String getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    /**
     * @param model the model to set
     */
    public void setModel(String model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    /**
     * @return the color
     */
    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * @param color the color to set
     */
    public void setColor(String color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

В классе представляющем модель таблице, не могу понять как правильно переопределить 3 метода :

```
package first_test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class TableModelForCar implements TableModel
{

    ArrayList<DataCarTable> listCar;
    DataCarTable carTable;
    public TableModelForCar( ArrayList<DataCarTable> listCar)
    {
        this.listCar = listCar;
    }




    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return listCar.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
    {
       switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: return "Марка";
            case 1: return "Модель";
            case 2: return "Колір";
            case 3: return "Ціна";
        }
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
    {
       return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        carTable = listCar.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: return carTable.getMark();
            case 1: return carTable.getModel();
            case 2: return carTable.getColor();
            case 3: return carTable.getPrice();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l)
        {
        }
}
```

**Нужна помощь с методами:**

```
  @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l)
    {
    }
```

**Подскажите как их правильно переопределить !!!**

**Обновление 1**

Вопрос с  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
решил так:

```
 @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
       carTable = listCar.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: carTable.setMark((String)aValue);
            break;
            case 1: carTable.setModel((String)aValue);
            break;
            case 2: carTable.setColor((String)aValue);
            break;
            case 3: carTable.setPrice(new Double(String.valueOf(aValue)));
            break;
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто наследуйтесь от **AbstractTableModel**. Сомневаюсь, что вам нужна кастомная реализация всех методов интерфейса **TableModel**.

```
   public class CarTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] columns = { "mark", "model", "color", "price" };

    public CarTableModel(List<Car> cars) {
        super();
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>(cars);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return cars.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch ( columnIndex ) {
            //..
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Car car = cars.get(rowIndex);
        switch ( columnIndex ) {
            case 0:
                car.setMark((String) aValue);
                break;
            case 1:
                car.setModel((String) aValue);
                break;
            //.. etc
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

}
```

Кроме того, никто вам не мешает их переопределить.

Comment: но если реализовать абстрактную модель и не переопределить этот метод то если он мне понадобится я не смогу его использовать !!!

Comment: Так вы сначала и решите, нужен он вам или нет. В абстрактном классе он не реализован как раз потому, что не требуется для вывода данных. Только, если ваша таблица должна редактироваться пользователем.

Comment: ну если спрашиваю, то думаю есть на то причина !!!

Comment: Обновил ответ. Надо больше восклицательных знаков.

Comment: точно так сделал ! Можно еще с с остальными двумя методами помочь ??

Comment: Они уже реализованы в AbstractTableModel. Откройте исходник. Обычно это CTRL + ЛКМ в IDE на названиии класса.